# iPad airplay display shows black screen when I create a new UIWindow

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, airplay, mirroring

[EDIT] 
I restarted the iPad and it fixed the issue. I'm leaving it here because stack overflow discouraged deleting the question

I have a weird thing happening on iPad Air 2. Using the method mentioned in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/WindowAndScreenGuide/UsingExternalDisplay/UsingExternalDisplay.html

I create a new `UIWindow` object for the secondary display connected through AirPlay.

```
- (void)checkForExistingScreenAndInitializeIfPresent {
   if ([[UIScreen screens] count] > 1)
   {
    // Get the screen object that represents the external display.
    UIScreen *secondScreen = [[UIScreen screens] objectAtIndex:1];
    // Get the screen's bounds so that you can create a window of the correct size.
    CGRect screenBounds = secondScreen.bounds;

    self.secondWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:screenBounds];
    self.secondWindow.screen = secondScreen;

    NSLog(@"Show external window");
    // Set up initial content to display...
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Test" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    UIViewController *controller = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
    self.secondWindow.rootViewController = controller;
    // Show the window.
    self.secondWindow.hidden = NO;
   }
```

}

When I run this code on an iPhone 5s, The code works perfectly and the secondary window is initialized. However, when I run this code from Xcode on the iPad Air 2, I only see a black screen. If the app is not run through Xcode, the app launches on the iPad but on the AirPlay display it only shows the home screen with the app icon highlighted. The audio is still routed through AirPlay.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A wild guess here but is there anything in the storyboard that you are trying to load that is "iPhone only" ? That could explain why it does not display on iPad.

Comment: @Ermiar You wouldn't believe it. After hours of not being able to figure it out, I restarted the iPad. Miraculously, it worked!

Comment: lol okay ! In this case I do not know if you need to answer the question yourself or just close it. Anyway, glad you found a solution.

Comment: @Ermiar I was trying to delete it but I can't seem to find the option

Comment: you do not have a button "delete" next to others under your post ?

Comment: I found the button but since the question is answered, stack overflow gave me a warning that answered questions shouldn't be deleted and after a couple, my account will be banned so I chose to just edit it.

Comment: Oh okay : so I think you should answer your question, this way it will be "done" from the point of view of other users

Answer (score 1):

Normally we change our UIWindow Color like this:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.backgroundColor = [UIColor myColor];
```

You can set your self.secondWindow color as:

```
secondWindow.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Answer (score 1):

This was a ridiculous case and the solution to it was just as ridiculous. I restarted the iPad and the issue went away.

Comment: I am facing same issue in iPad 2. In my case some time it happens frequently. 
Did you found any reason or better solutions?

Comment: No I'm sorry @Deepak it only happened to me that one time and after it went away it never came back.

Comment: thanks @Matt,
Sorry my device is not iPad 2 it is iPad 3,3. 
Device info-:
Model -: iPad Wi-Fi + 4G (LTE/GSM) - iPad3,3
iOS-: 9.3.1 (13E238)